# How do I subscribe to contract events in Web3.js 4.0?

Tags: web3js

I have deployed a contract factory, Contract.sol, which emits the address of every contract it deploys.

I would like to subscribe to these events in my JS application.

It seems that the interface has changed in the new version of web3.js, so that my attempts to subscribe aren't working.

What's the proper way to sign up to the events emitted below?

```
event contractDeployed (address_to);
...
emit contractDeployed (new contract);
```